# how to scrape the data of specific html table(using class) using url in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-visualization

I want to scrape data from a website by using its class. The table data is generated on run time.I tried with below code, but it doesn't work.

```
tables = soup.findAll("table", { "class" : "tab05" })
print len(tables) 

for row in tables[0].findAll("tr"):
    for col in row.findAll("td"):
        print col.getText()
```

it is showing some different tables.

Comment: Can you share URL? Without it it's hard to help you...

Comment: Did you try to use`find()` instead of `findAll()`? or are there many tables with the same class?

Comment: There might be other tables with the same class name, try using id

Comment: none of this tricks work for me.

Comment: they wont  unless you provide what is html structure of table looks like better provide the url and addition to it there may be chances of ip block or js call or ajax call